# Formula for permutations and combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose there are $27$ possible letters $\{A, B,... ,Z\}$ and they can be arranged in any order including spaces, capitalization, order.

Is the formula

$P(n,r) = n!(n−r)!$

still correct?

Comment: What's the extra letter?

Comment: More relevantly:  your question isn't clear.  What  precisely do you mean by $P(n,r)$?  How, for example, can "spaces" be used?

Comment: The most common interpretation of the symbol $P(n,r)$ is where $P(n,r)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, not $n!\times (n-r)!$ and this counts the number of ways in which you may make a sequence of length $r$ out of $n$ available characters where no character may repeat.  Whether or not this is at all relevant to your problem is unclear since you have neglected to give much of any clarification as to what is wanting to be counted.

Comment: Now... you need to clarify... Are characters allowed to be repeated?  Are we asking how many possible sequences exist in total of any length, or are we asking how many sequences of a specific length?  Are there any other limitations, such as not allowing multiple spaces to occur in a row, or no space occurring as the leading character, etc...?  In the end, it will likely fall under one of the standard problem types described in the [twelve-fold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of spaces make a word unique, then I can have infinite permutations.

If not, then it is essentially an extra character. Also, capitalisation would add another 26 characters to your set. Then you can permute over 26+26+1 characters using the standard formula.

(You might have to remove some permutations which have a leading or trailing whitespace; if you don't consider those unique.)